# Cross-Product of a Triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem about vectors.
When 3 coordinates of A, B, and C form a triangle in a 3D, the sum of $(\vec {AB}+\vec {BC}+\vec {CA}=\vec 0)$ is always zero. Then when the $\vec {AB}$ x $\vec {BC}$, it is equal to $\vec {BC}$ x $\vec {CA}$ and $\vec {CA}$ x $\vec {AB}$. Why does this happen?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "when the $\vec {AB}$ x $\vec {BC}$"?

Comment: Any reaction to the answers you have received, Pussy?

Comment: It means that when I do the cross product of $\vec {AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" an answer by clicking in the check mark next to it, if you find that it has answered your question to your satisfaction. If your question hasn't been answered to your satisfaction, you have the option of pointing out what is lacking, and asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$AB+BC+CA=0$,
$(AB+BC+CA)\times BC=0\times BC=0$,
$AB\times BC+BC\times BC+CA\times BC=0$
but $BC\times BC=0$
so $AB\times BC+CA\times BC=0$
so $AB\times BC=-CA\times BC=BC\times CA$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, the length of each of those cross products is equal to twice the area of the triangle. The three vectors are coplanar, so as long as you’re careful to take them in the correct order, the cross products will all point in the same direction.

Comment: What’s wrong with this answer, o anonymous downvoter?

Comment: nothing is wrong with your answer!